# Cannot subscribe to own topics (in rostest)

Tags: rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm still writing integration test and I'm stuct at asimple exmaple where I want my testcase to publish a message and also subscrib to the same topic

```
class AdvancedTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_joint_states(self):
        rospy.init_node('test_vehicle_controller', anonymous=True)

        joint_state = JointState()
        joint_state.name = ['lift_actor', 'wheel_main_rotation', 'wheel_main_steer']
        joint_state.velocity = (0.02069770811665661, 0.0014280281623658617, 1.1028179833702783e-05)
        joint_state.position = (0.9990335843981955, -0.12971652493225605, -0.0031193465124985664)
        joint_state.effort = (37.26698108917237, 0.0, 0.0)

        rospy.Subscriber('/my_ns/joint_states', JointState, self.callback_state)
        pubA = rospy.Publisher('/my_ns/joint_states', JointState, queue_size=10)
        pubA.publish(joint_state)

    def callback_state(self, state):
        rospy.loginfo("received " + repr(state))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import rostest
    rostest.rosrun(PKG, 'test_joint_states', AdvancedTestSuite)
```

but nothing happens the callback is called. I can not even debug what wrong. Any Ideas ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275924/cannot-subscribe-to-own-topics-(in-rostest)/) by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2017-11-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-14**:
And just a note: `rostest` is not subscribing to anything. `rostest` is just the test driver here in this case. Your code is subscribing.

Suggestion: change the question title to reflect this better.

**Comment by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on 2017-11-14**:
Thank you for your comment. This shows again that I dont fully understand internal ROS concepts (yet).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-14**:
No problem. We're all posting here to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It takes some time for subscriptions to be setup (this is a networked middleware, not a local function call). There is probably on the order of a few milliseconds between the creation if your publisher and your subscriber, you then `publish(..)` and your program exits *immediately*. Try to add a `time.sleep(..)` at appropriate places to see whether that is the problem.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on 2017-11-14**:
I already added a `time.sleep(...)` without a whole loop after the `publish(...)` without anything luck. Do I also need to wait before the publish ? It would also bei nice to somehow debug the situation. But `rostopic` for example complaints thats the ros master is not reachable

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-14**:\

> Do I also need to wait before the publish ?

that is probably the most important place to sleep.

If you're not a fan of doing this time-based, and would rather do it state-based (I would), then you could use `pubA.get_num_connections()` to wait for a connection before publishing.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-14**:
See [rospy.Publisher](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Publisher-class.html) for the API docs for that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-14**:\

> It would also bei nice to somehow debug the situation.

well this is Python, and your test is basically a Python script, so `pdb` could perhaps help here.

But as there is a network involved, and most things are asynchronous, debugging could prove difficult.

**Comment by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on 2017-11-15**:
@gvdhoorn I solved it with a `time.sleep(...)` before the publish, thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-15**:
Suggestion: use a state-based approach. If for whatever reason the publisher and / or subscriber need more time to initialise (perhaps due to resource contention with other processes on the machine running your tests), you run the risk of the test failing for no good reason.